How to number an example？
I want to number definition and some examples. These are my code
\documentclass{ctexart}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{bm}
\newcommand{\Ob}{\bm{$Ob(\mathcal{C})$}}
\newcommand{\morphism}{\textbf{morphism}}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defi}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{ex}{Examples}[section]
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{theorem}[section]
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem*{remark}{Remark}
\counterwithin{figure}{section}
\numberwithin{ex}{defi}
\title{Notes of Category Theory}
\author{MGIO}
\date{2024.10.15}
\newenvironment{myquote}{\begin{quote} \zihao{5}\kaishu}{\end{quote}}
\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \tableofcontents
    \textit{Basic Category Theory}
    \section{what is category}
    \begin{defi}[categroy]%Definition 1.1
    \end{defi}
\begin{ex}[\textbf{Set}] %Example 1.1.1
\end{ex}
\begin{defi}[isomorphism]%Definition 1.2
\end{defi}
\begin{ex}%Example 1.2.1
\end{ex}
\begin{ex}%it output will be 1.2.2, which I want to it will be 1.1.2, because it is an example of definition 1.1
\end{ex}
\end{document}

and output like

Definition 1.1
Example 1.1.1
Example 1.1.2
Definition 1.2
Example 1.2.1
Example 1.2.2
Example 1.2.3

Example 1.1.1 means the first example of Definition 1.1, Example 1.2.2 means the second example of Definition 1.2. However, Example 1.2.3 is actually the example of Definition 1.1, but I must declear Definition 1.2 to introduce Example 1.2.3(so Definition 1.2 must in front of Example 1. 2.3), by considering it is actually Definition 1.1, I want to number it as Example 1.1.3. How can I do this?

Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at our starter guide to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Try with \newtheorem{defi}{Definition}[section] \newtheorem{ex}[defi]{Example}

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz. Thank you! I complete my code, and delete some math part which is not important for this question.

@MadyYuvi The output will be Definition 1.1 Example 1.2… However I want to number defition by two numbers like 1.1, the first number means it is in first section, the second number means it is the first definition of the first section. And I want to number example by three numbers like 1.1.2 which means it is the second example of the first definition of the first section. Anyway, thank you!

So, if I understand correctly, you want the numbers to be independent from where the example is actually printed. It might be easiest to enter them manually then.

@JasperHabicht It makes sense. Thanks！

Hope this will meet the expectation:
\documentclass{ctexart}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{bm}
\newcommand{\Ob}{\bm{$Ob(\mathcal{C})$}}
\newcommand{\morphism}{\textbf{morphism}}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defi}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{ex}{Examples}[defi]
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{theorem}[section]
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem*{remark}{Remark}
\counterwithin{figure}{section}
%\numberwithin{ex}{defi}
\title{Notes of Category Theory}
\author{MGIO}
\date{2024.10.15}
\newenvironment{myquote}{\begin{quote} \zihao{5}\kaishu}{\end{quote}}
\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \tableofcontents
    \textit{Basic Category Theory}
    \section{what is category}
    \begin{defi}[categroy]%Definition 1.1
    \end{defi}
\begin{ex}[\textbf{Set}] %Example 1.1.1
\end{ex}
\begin{defi}[isomorphism]%Definition 1.2
\end{defi}
\begin{ex}%Example 1.2.1
\end{ex}
\begin{ex}%it output will be 1.2.2, which I want to it will be 1.1.2, because it is an example of definition 1.1
\end{ex}
\end{document}



Thanks！ Is there any way change Examples 1.2.2 to Examples 1.1.2 but still keeps it under the Examples 1.2.1？

Sorry, couldn't able to understand exactly what you mean, can you provide more clarity? (actually I'm poor in English :-(( excuse me

I am sorry, It's my fault, I am not native English speaker. Let me show you what I expect.

For example: Definition 1.1 integer Examples 1.1.1 999 Definition 1.2 division
Examples 1.2.1 2÷3=2/3 Examples 1.2.2 4÷2=2. 2 is an integer, so I want to make it like Examples 1.1.2 4÷2=2. And it used division, so I want to make it after the Defitnition 1.2. Anyway, thanks for your kindness!
